# ACL post Google calendar domain not found

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to add a new domain to my acl list of my calendar for the application Robin powered.
I login with our admin account of our domain and i'm able to view/edit the calendar via https://calendar.google.com/. I have all the rights on the calendar.

I followed the steps described here (https://support.robinpowered.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001164606-Allow-outside-G-Suite-domains-to-book-your-resource-calendars) but still receive an error Domain not found. I can view all the ACLs of the calendar when i run following command: https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/myid@resource.calendar.google.com/acl

when i try to POST following info, i received the error NOT FOUND.

```
{
 "scope": {
 "type": "domain",
 "value": "<domain>.com"
 },
 "role": "freeBusyReader"
}
```

response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "notFound",
                "message": "Not Found"
            }
        ],
        "code": 404,
        "message": "Not Found"
    }
}
```

I already contact gsuite support but they told me to create a ticket on stackoverflow to get in touch with the developers of the api.

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: hi @ziganotschka, i'm using the try this api on the following link: [https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/acl/insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/acl/insert) and receive this error message.

Comment: Two things: 1.Is the calendar you want to share  a calendar of the domain whose admin you are (a Google domain). 2. Is the domain you want to share the calendar with a Google domain?

Comment: We have one bot user with admin rights but i'm running this call on the admin user of our gsuite account. I'll try it with the other user in a couple of minutes. The domain we want to add is a Google domain.

Comment: You should run this call as an editor or owner of the calendar. Is it a Google Calendar from your Google domain?

Comment: hi @ziganotschka i tried this with following account and still the same issue:
  {
   "kind": "calendar#aclRule",
   "etag": "\"id\"",
   "id": "user:bot@<domain>",
   "scope": {
    "type": "user",
    "value": "bot@<domain>"
   },
   "role": "owner"
  },

Comment: The update (PUT) function give me following output:
`{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "calendar",
    "reason": "invalidAclId",
    "message": "Provided acl id is invalid."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Provided acl id is invalid."
 }
}`

While the GET method of this acl id works.

Comment: `403` means permission issue. Probably because you try to make an invalid user the calendar owner or you do not have the rights to transfer ownership (because you are not owner?). I am not sure what you mean by "bot user"? Can you try with a normal domain user? I am not sure how "Robin powered" is related to the issue, this is why I am asking if the calendar you want to share is your regular Google domain calendar, e.g. your primary calendar.

Comment: Hi @ziganotschka my "bot user" is a regular domain user bot@mydomain.com and is owner of the calendar. Tried with the admin user of the domain as well and have the same issues. The calendar is a resource we have created via the admin panel > Apps > G suite > Calendar > Resources. I would think that the admin of my domain have all the permissions to edit the resources?

Comment: hi @ziganotschka it seems like there is a problem with the domain i want to add. I created a new resources added a domain that we own and is a Google account and no issues with that. When i try the domain of our client i ended with the same error. Thank you for your time! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Is your client's domain not a GSuite domain? I am glad the issue was solved!